Ingress is not working on my Kubernetes clusters
I have built Kubernetes clusters that consists of four nodes.
But ingress is not reachable from control plane or deployed host.
I tried to deploy services by NodePort then the service is reachable from any node IPs.
My ingress is deployed specific IP address so my Kubernetes is works fine so that I consider my network config has something wrong but I'm not sure.
Application config for each nodes:
ufw allow k8s-worker k8s-calico
ufw allow in vxlan.calico
ufw allow out vxlan.calico
ufw allow k8s-pods from 192.168.0.60/30
ufw allow k8s-nginx-ingress from 192.168.0.60/30

Detail application config:
# For control plane
[k8s-cp]
title=Kubernetes for control plane
description=Kubernetes for control plane
ports=80,443,2379,2380,6443,10250:10252,10259,10257,30000:32767/tcp

# For worker node
[k8s-worker]
title=Kubernetes for worker node
description=Kubernetes worker node
ports=80,443,10250,30000:32767/tcp

# Common config
[k8s-calico]
title=callico
description=callico for kubernetes CNI
ports=47,179/tcp|4789/udp|2379/tcp

[k8s-pods]
title=Kubernetes Pods Communication
description=Allow traffic from Kubernetes pods within the CIDR range.
ports=1:65535/tcp|1:65535/udp

[k8s-nginx-ingress]
title=Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller
description=Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller
ports=8443/tcp

Deployments:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
  labels:
    name: nginx-test
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: nginx-test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:1.14.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "0.1"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "0.1"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: nginx-test
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: nginx

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test
  namespace: nginx-test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
      host: sparrow03.local

The ingress status:
Name:             ingress-test
Labels:           app=nginx
Namespace:        nginx-test
Address:          192.168.0.63
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host             Path  Backends
  ----             ----  --------
  sparrow03.local  
                   /   nginx-service:8080 (172.16.184.3:80,172.16.214.3:80)
Annotations:       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                  ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    4m12s (x3 over 5m3s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync

There is a specification of each node.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Kubernetes: 1.29.3
CRI: containerd
CNI: Calico
Ingress class: nginx
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4


Consider to ask sys-admin and networking questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Check if the service and ingress configurations are configured correctly and there are no restrictive Network Policies. Also, check the logs of the nginx ingress controller for any errors.

Thanks I will repost this question on servefault.com. By the way, the communication between service and ingress is not reachable now. But ingress controller doesn't have any error.
